# Ember.js passing parameters from views to controller functions

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have an Ember.js app as follows (borrowed from [this article](http://www.andymatthews.net/read/2012/03/20/Reversing-the-output-of-an-Ember.js-content-array) on andyMatthews.net):

View:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" >
    {{view App.UserTextField}}
    {{#each App.recentUsersArray.reverse tagName="ul"}}
        <li>{{this}}</li>
    {{/each}}
</script>​
```

App:

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.UserTextField = Ember.TextField.extend({
    insertNewline: function(){
        var term = this.get('value');
        App.recentUsersArray.pushObject(term);
    }
});

App.recentUsersArray = Em.ArrayController.create({
    content: ['noelle', 'evan', 'mason'],
    reverse: function(){
        return this.get('content').toArray().reverse();
    }.property('content.@each').cacheable(),
});​
```

But I'd like to pass a parameter to App.recentUsersArray.reverse from the view (for example, to set the number of reversed items to be returned).  I run into a problem because while you can accept the parameter on the controller function, it doesn't seem like you can pass it from the view.  I was imagining something like this if you wanted to pass the parameter 3 to the reverse function on the controller:

```
{{#each App.recentUsersArray.reverse(3) tagName="ul"}}
   <li>{{this}}</li>
{{/each}}
```

but it throws an error (Uncaught Error: Parse error)...thoughts?  The ultimate goal would be to create three `<ul>`'s, each with a different number of elements *without* creating a different function for each length (i.e., `App.recentUsersArray.reverseThree()`, `App.recentUsersArray.reverseFive()`, etc. ). I also don't want to make three different controllers, because each of the `<ul>`'s should be using the same data source, just sliced up differently.

Comment: You have to read about how computed properties work before understanding why what you're asking for doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Ember can come across as an odd paradigm. Maybe try:

```
App.recentUsersArray = Em.ArrayController.create({
  recentCount: 3
  content: ['noelle', 'evan', 'mason'],
  reverse: function(){
      var max = this.get('recentCount');
      return this.get('content').reverse().slice(0, max)
  }.property('content.@each', 'recentCount').cacheable(),
});​

//some event handler
App.recentUsersArray.set('recentCount', count)
```

I don't think `toArray()` is necessary, plus the docs say it does not guarantee the order of elements returned:
http://docs.emberjs.com/#doc=Ember.Enumerable&method=.toArray&src=false